# Driving column From another Column using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone please help me on this how I can drive a currency column from value date section header which is shown below using pandas? I try but fail to get it.

| Value date | Currency(Driven form Value date) |
| --- | --- |
| Deposits HKD |  |
| 01 Mar 201 | HKD |
| 04 Mar 2019 | HKD |
| 04 Mar 2019 | HKD |
| 05 Mar 2019 | HKD |
| 05 Mar 2019 | HKD |
| Deposits SGD |  |
| 02 Mar 2019 | SGD |
| Deposits USD |  |
| 01 Mar 2019 | USD |
| 12 Mar 2019 | USD |
| 29 Mar 2019 | USD |

Comment: Hi, can you update your answer in a better format, so we can help you better?

Comment: hi @IbrahimBerber  I updated my question please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `extract` the values, then `ffill` and put empty strings on heading rows using `np.where`:

```
z = df['Value date'].str.extract('Deposits (.*)')
df['Currency'] = np.where(z.isna(), z.ffill(), '')
df
```

Output:

```
      Value date Currency
0   Deposits HKD         
1     01 Mar 201      HKD
2    04 Mar 2019      HKD
3    04 Mar 2019      HKD
4    05 Mar 2019      HKD
5    05 Mar 2019      HKD
6   Deposits SGD         
7    02 Mar 2019      SGD
8   Deposits USD         
9    01 Mar 2019      USD
10   12 Mar 2019      USD
11   29 Mar 2019      USD
```

Comment: @aTcCreator Great, can you then please accept the answer?